# WSUS difference between Windows 10 and Windows 10 GDR-DU Products

Tags: wsus, windows-10

In the Choose Products screen of WSUS configuration, there is an option for both **Windows 10 GDR-DU** and **Windows 10**:

[image]

What is the difference between the two? I can't find any Microsoft documentation that explains the difference between the products.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GDR-DU mean General Distribution Release (Dynamic Update)

Sadly from TechNet no resource seem wrote for that. From the information I have it's file kept for upgrading from a build to another, to prevent a fresh system re-install (like build 1511 to 1607). (not for normal updating).

A description for GDR-DU from a Microsoft source there, official (but on an archived mailing list). (https://marc.info/?l=patchmanagement&m=147085158401556&w=2)

> > GDRDU just means that when you install Windows 10
> >     1607, it will automatically download and inject the
> >     update as part of the upgrade process, as long as
> >     dynamic update is enabled (which is the default). 
> >     It's a mechanism to get fixes in place without
> >     refreshing the entire OS image.

See there for a quick info, not official, but still point to the same answer than the Microsoft's source: http://www.urtech.ca/2016/12/solved-what-do-the-windows-10-product-names-mean-in-wsus/

> Windows 10 GDR-DU: GDR = General Distribution Release, DU=Dynamic
>   Update. These updates are only used by the current GDR build of
>   Windows 10 when it is trying to perform a Dynamic Update (see item 5
>   above).
>
> Item 5: Windows 10 Dynamic Update: This includes only updates to the
>   setup process that occurs when one build of Windows 10 is trying to
>   update to a new build of Windows 10 (i.e. 1511 to 1607).

A more generic description for GDR-DU.

> By default, all components on Windows systems start on the GDR branch
>   following each major release. When you install updates from Windows
>   Update for a GDR component, it gets upgraded with the GDR version.
>
> When you install a specific Hotfix, the files and components in the
>   Hotfix package are migrated to the LDR branch. At this point, that
>   particular component is marked as a LDR component. If you install a
>   newer Update over this component, the Windows servicing technology
>   will automatically install the appropriate latest version from the LDR
>   branch for you. This is possible because each Update package ships
>   with both the GDR and LDR versions of the component.
>
> Once a component is marked as a LDR component, the only way to move
>   back to the GDR branch is to uninstall all Hotfixes for that
>   component, or move to the next available service pack.

Quoted text from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2008/10/21/windows-hotfixes-and-updates-how-do-they-work/

The question after is, why you can select GDR-DU alone without the Dynamic Update too.